# Speed up a video without audio to 2x with FFmpeg in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am working on a project in which I need to speed up a mute video. I did a little digging around and found the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=PTS/2" output.mkv
```

Tried to use it in android as follows.

```
new String[]{"-y", "-i", inputFileAbsolutePath, "-filter_complex", "setpts=PTS/2", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "[a]", "-b:v", "2097k", "-r", "60", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", fileOutput};
```

It doesn't even show anything in the Logcat.

I have also tried a few other solutions but no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to view the log from the `ffmpeg` process it would provide an error:

```
Output with label 'v' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.
```

So either properly label and map the filter output:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "setpts=PTS/2[v]" -map "[v]" -b:v 2097k -r 60 -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4
```

...or omit the labels and rely on the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex setpts=PTS/2 -b:v 2097k -r 60 -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4
```